# Android Studio: Room: error: Cannot find getter for field

Tags: android, android-room

I am using room database for local caching. Inside my entity I have other objects whose getters have a return type of an interface related to their purpose. However room cannot find a getter for the fields. My goal is to use these interfaces as return types so that I can add data into one array from multiple remote sources. How can I do this while achieving flexible and good abstraction?

```
public interface Venue {
  Location getLocation();
  Contact getContact();
}

public interface Location {
  double getLongitude();
  double getLatitude();
}

public interface Contact {
  String getPhoneNumber();
  String getFacebookUsername();
}

public class VenueSourceOne implements Venue{
   private VenueSourceOneLocation venueSourceOneLocation;
   private VenueSourceOneContact venueSourceOneContact;

   Location getLocation(){
      return venueSourceOneLocation;
   }

   Contact getContact(){
      return venueSourceOneContact
   }
}

public class VenueSourceTwo implements Venue{
   private VenueSourceTwoLocation venueSourceTwoLocation;
   private VenueSourceTwoContact venueSourceTwoContact;

   Location getLocation(){
      return venueSourceTwoLocation;
   }

   Contact getContact(){
      return venueSourceTwoContact
   }
}


public class Main{
   ....add to a List<Venue> and do something on the UI
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the venue interface to an abstract class for reason other that the problem I presented:

**from**

```
public interface Venue {
  Location getLocation();
  Contact getContact();
}
```

**to**

```
public abstract class Venue {
      public abstract Location getLocation();
      public abstract Contact getContact();
}
```

The real solution to my problem is below:

**from**

```
public class VenueSourceOne implements Venue{
   private VenueSourceOneLocation venueSourceOneLocation;
   private VenueSourceOneContact venueSourceOneContact;

   Location getLocation(){
      return venueSourceOneLocation;
   }

   Contact getContact(){
      return venueSourceOneContact
   }
}

public class VenueSourceTwo implements Venue{
   private VenueSourceTwoLocation venueSourceTwoLocation;
   private VenueSourceTwoContact venueSourceTwoContact;

   Location getLocation(){
      return venueSourceTwoLocation;
   }

   Contact getContact(){
      return venueSourceTwoContact
   }
}
```

**to**

```
public class VenueSourceOne extends Venue{
   private VenueSourceOneLocation location;
   private VenueSourceOneContact contact;

   @Override
   VenueSourceOneLocation getLocation(){
      return location;
   }

   @Override
   VenueSourceOneContact getContact(){
      return contact;
   }
}

public class VenueSourceTwo extends Venue{
   private VenueSourceTwoLocation location;
   private VenueSourceTwoContact contact;

   @Override
   VenueSourceTwoLocation getLocation(){
      return location;
   }

   @Override
   VenueSourceTwoContact getContact(){
      return contact;
   }
}
```

The list will use the general type specified by the abstract class when retrieving the data from the source, while room will store the data using the specific type.